# sql select query summing the results

Tags: sql

hello i need select query.

```
+--------------------------+
|  A                    B  |
+--------------------------+
| ------------------------ |
| x                    5   |
| y                    10  |
| z                    15  |
| t                    20  |
+--------------------------+
```

query must only sum x and y . not the others. (example below)

```
A                    B
------------------------
p(as x+y)            15
z                    15
t                    20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a UNION?

```
select 'p' as a, sum(b) as b
from the_table
where a in ('x','y')

union all

select a, b
from the_table
where a not in ('x','y')
```

Answer (score 2):

You want conditional grouping :

```
select (case when a in ('x', 'y') then 'p' else a end) as a, sum(b) as b
from table t
group by (case when a in ('x', 'y') then 'p' else a end);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when a in ('x', 'y') then 'p' else a end) as a,
       sum(b)
from t
group by (case when a in ('x', 'y') then 'p' else a end) ;
```